# how to return response from Kafka consumer using kafka js in router in node js

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

i am using the node js.
i have the code below to run the kafka confuguration using kafka js. All is working good, i send the message using producer and recieve the message using consumer but i want to return back response form consumer to show the response in router so that i test the apis in postman.

i have router in router folder

router.get('/fetch-users', UserController.getUsers);

in controller

```
module.exports.getUsers = async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const users = await userModel.find()
        console.log(users)
        await kafkaNode.produce('get-users', {
            value: 3,
            data: 'data'
        })
        const resData = await kafkaNode.consume('response-data').then(res => console.log('resss:', res)).catch(error => error)
        res.send(resData)
    } catch (e) {
        res.send(e)
    }
```

and in main file index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
require('./db/db')
const routes = require('./router/user.js')

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));
app.use(routes)




// call the `produce` function and log an error if it occurs
// produce().catch((err) => {
//  console.error("error in producer: ", err)
// })

// start the consumer, and log any errors
// consume().catch((err) => {
//  console.error("error in consumer: ", err)
// })

app.listen('3000', () => {
    console.log('server is listen on 3000')
})
```

and this is kafka configuration file
const { Kafka } = require('kafkajs');

```
    class KafkaLibrary
    {
    #kafka;
    #clientId;
    #brokers;
    #producer;
    #consumer;
    #groupId;
    #currentTopic;

    constructor(clientId='app', brokers=['127.0.0.1:9092'], groupId='test-group')
    {
        if(Array.isArray(brokers)) {
            this.#brokers = brokers;
        } else {
            return "brokers should be in array format"
        }
        this.#clientId = clientId;
        // this.#topics = topics;
        this.#groupId = groupId;
        // this.#payload = payload;
    }
    producerConnect() 
    {
        this.#kafka = new Kafka({
            clientId: this.#clientId,
            brokers: this.#brokers,
            requestTimeout: 25000,
            // retry: {
            //     initialRetryTime: 100,
            //     retries: 8
            // }
        });
        this.#producer = this.#kafka.producer();
        // this.#consumer = this.#kafka.consumer({ groupId: this.#groupId });
    }
    consumerConnect() 
    {
        this.#kafka = new Kafka({
            clientId: this.#clientId,
            brokers: this.#brokers,
            requestTimeout: 25000,
            // retry: {
            //     initialRetryTime: 100,
            //     retries: 8
            // }
        });
        this.#consumer = this.#kafka.consumer({ groupId: this.#groupId });
    }
    // static init() 
    // {
    //     console.log('hello')
    //     this.connect();
    // }
    async produce(topic, payload)
    {
        this.producerConnect();
        const messages = JSON.stringify(payload)
        await this.#producer.connect();
        await this.#producer.send({
            topic,
            messages: [
                { value: messages },
            ],
        })
        // await this.#producer.disconnect();
    }
    async consume(topic)
    {
        this.consumerConnect();
        // const topic = this.#topics
        await this.#consumer.connect()
        await this.#consumer.subscribe({ topic, fromBeginning: true })
        await this.#consumer.run({
            eachMessage: async ({ topic, partition, message }) => {
                try {
                    console.log({
                        value: message.value.toString(),
                    })
                    return message.value.toString()
                } catch(e) {
                    console.log(e)
                }
                
            },
        });
    }
}

module.exports = new KafkaLibrary;
```

Comment: i think the problem is when you use `await` and a callback pattern - meaning you pass callback , and that cause your code to skip ahead after your await. 

remove the `.then() .catch()` from `consume` .

Comment: thanks to response me, sir i remove the callback but still i did not get the response

Comment: sir the main issue is that when i call response.send() it did not show any thing after calling consume

Comment: o.k : in your consume you are just registering the callback to be called when a message get processed, you can not ! return value from callback to your server code.

Comment: You shouldn't rely on kafka having a response immediately. Do more research into the CQRS pattern. More specifically, have an always active kafka consumer running in the background populating a database. An HTTP POST event can send/update a user record to some input topic, some other consumer (not your api) will receive this, write to some storage, then your api can then query the storage, or some read-only replica, directly

Comment: thanks @OneCricketeer can you please send me any article related to this. because my requirement is to return the response from consumer. My scenario is First producer send the topic having message to other microservice and and the consumer listen the producer topic and catch the message i again send the producer to different topic to first microservice and here again consumer listen the producer topic and here i show the response coming from the consumer

Comment: There's plenty of documentation on CQRS. It's not Kafka specific. Start with site like https://microservices.io My point is that HTTP clients have timeouts. There's no guarantee that a consumer will get any event within that time